# jQuery: add css() and fadeToggle

Tags: jquery, css, hamburger-menu

I know, very noob question: I got this code on a Wordpress website and it works properly

```
jQuery('.hamburger').click(function() {
jQuery('.menu-container').fadeToggle( "0.3s", "swing" ),
});
```

How can I add to this script css() method?
I've tried something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
    jQuery('.hamburger').click(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-container').fadeToggle( "0.3s", "swing" );
    jQuery(".bar2").css({"display":"none");
    jQuery(".bar").css({"width":"40px","margin-bottom":"-2px");
    jQuery(".bar1").css({"transform":"rotate(45deg)");
    jQuery(".bar1").css({"transform":"rotate(-45deg)");

});
```

What's the proper way to achieve my goal?

Comment: remove the `{` after css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `.css()` is wrong. you should use either `.css(property, value)` or `.css({property1: value1, property2: value2})`

I created a snippet for you here.

```js
jQuery('.hamburger').click(function() {
jQuery('.menu-container').fadeToggle( "0.3s", "swing" );
jQuery(".bar2").css("display","none");
jQuery(".bar").css({"width":"40px","margin-bottom":"-2px"});
jQuery(".bar1").css("transform","rotate(45deg)");
jQuery(".bar1").css("transform","rotate(-45deg)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=hamburger>Click me</button>
<div class=menu-container>Menu Container</div>
<div class=bar>Bar</div>
<div class=bar1>Bar1</div>
<div class=bar2>Bar2</div>
```

BTW, I don't know why you are rotating `bar1` twice. But, I used your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks this works, but I wonder why fadeToggle also works in reverse while the rest of the code does not

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to use `.css` in jquery

```
$("p").css("color", "red");
```

Working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").css("color", "blue");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This will turn to blue when button is clicked</p>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

snippet below,